# Is it possible to pass the scope from one controller file to another file

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, d3.js, crossfilter

I've two controllers 1. base controller and 2. defect controller, both are different files. I want to pass the scope value or variable from one controller to another.
If the both controllers in same file means we can share it, but the problem is files are different.

How can I pass the scope from one to another controller?

Comment: using services is the way to go, but it can also be done using `$rootScope` (not advised but just throwing in the possibilities)

Answer (score 0):

Using a service is the best way to communicate between the controllers. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: yes, am using rest services for both files but how can I share the common value from one to another controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to
write a service

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.service('sharedService', function(){
 this.shared = null;
 return {
  setShared: function(val){this.shared = val;},
  getShared: function(){return this.shared;}
 }
})
```

now inject this service into your controllers

```
//controller in file one
var app = angular.module('myApp'); // don't use [] if module is already inititalized
app.controller('settingCtrl', function($scope, sharedService){
 var shared = "Biscuits";
 sharedService.setShared(shared);
})

//controller in file two
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('readingCtrl', function($scope, sharedService){
 var shared= sharedService.getShared();
 console.log(shared); // 'Biscuits', recieved from other controller
})
```

just make sure to include these two files in the html after you've initialized angular

Comment: is it possible to use those two controllers from two different files?